# Cannot expand and substitute the contents of a variable in Bash

Tags: json, bash, curl

I am using Gitbash, GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys). 
I am running a bash script that looks like this

**CODE CHUNK 1**

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "x-customheader:customstuff" \
   -d \
'{
  Gigantic json payload contents in here
}' \
'http://localhost:5000/api/123'
```

This works fine.  Basically it posts a giant payload to an endpoint and all is well. The problem is when I attempt to substitute the url for a value from a variable, I get a curl error,
***curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl***

**CODE CHUNK 2**

```
stuff=\'http://localhost:5000/api/123\'
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "x-customheader:customstuff" \
   -d \
'{
  Gigantic json payload contents in here
}' \
$stuff
```

If I `echo $stuff` immediately after the `stuff=\'http://localhost:5000/api/123\'`, I get 'http://localhost:5000/api/123'.  This is the same value as I had hard-coded in code chunk 1, single ticks and all. There is something hiding behind the scenes in how that url is being evaluated after the variable has been expanded.  I need to get the same behavior as a hard coded url.

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at this error message:

> curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Notice the single-quote in front of `http`.
The `curl` command surely knows the `http` protocol, but not the `'http` protocol!

The way you wrote it, the single-quotes are part of the value of `stuff`:

> ```
> stuff=\'http://localhost:5000/api/123\'
> ```

Remove those, write like this:

```
stuff='http://localhost:5000/api/123'
```

If you have variables inside your real string,
and you want them expanded, then use double-quotes instead of single-quotes:

```
stuff="http://localhost:5000/api/123"
```

Equally important,
when you use `$stuff` as a parameter of `curl`,
you must double-quote it.
If you just write `curl $stuff`,
then the shell may interpret some characters in `$stuff` before passing to `curl`.
To protect from that,
you must write `curl "$stuff"`.

The complete command:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "x-customheader:customstuff" \
   -d \
'{
  Gigantic json payload contents in here
}' \
"$stuff"
```

Finally, make sure that after each `\` at the end of lines,
there's nothing after the `\` on each line,
the `\` must be at the very end.

Comment: I needed the ' to be literals. The single ' are a part of the value of $stuff.  If you examine the difference between the last line in Code Chunk 1 & 2, the difference is  Chunk 1 has 'url ' (Tick URL and a Tick).  Code Chunk 2 has  $stuff.  Expansion of that variable demands that the end result is 'url ' not url.  I need $stuff to be expanded to 'http://localhost:5000/api/123'. .

Comment: @MarkIrvin Have you tried as I wrote it? It should work. Rest assured, I understand what I'm talking about. Try it, by copy-pasting so you don't miss an important detail. Every single character in there is important. I think you're confused about quoting in Bash. Your confusion might come from `curl ... 'http://localhost:5000/api/'`. It may look like that the single quotes are part of the URL, but they are not, the shell removes them before passing to `curl`. If you write `curl ... "'http://localhost:5000/api/'"` then the single-quotes will be part, and the command will fail. Try as I wrote.

Comment: @MarkIrvin I added more details to my answer. I hope it's clearer now, let me know if you still have some doubts or questions, I'm happy to clear them up.

Comment: Curl did add confusion to what I was doing.  I have used your suggestion and can get closer to solving my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you define stuff with the `' '` ?

Try it like that:

```
stuff="http://localhost:5000/api/123"
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "x-customheader:customstuff" \
   -d \
'{
  Gigantic json payload contents in here
}' \
"$stuff"
```

---

Also, don't put variables in single quotes, because bash is not available to understand them.

```
stuff="http://localhost:5000/api/123"
echo "$stuff"
>> http://localhost:5000/api/123
echo '$stuff'
>> $stuff
```